# Swift3 not playing nicely with my JSON file

Tags: json, xcode, swift3

I have the following code:

```
let urlString = "https://str8red.com/jsonoverallleaderboard/"

let url = URL(string: urlString)
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!) { (data, response, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("there was an error")
        print(error)
    } 
    do {  
        let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [String:Any]
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
}        
}.resume()
```

which is returning the following error on the "let parsedData" line:

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI'
```

The JSON iIam using is from the website https://str8red.com/jsonoverallleaderboard/ and is in the following format:

```
[["shanu", "1056"], ["snookro", "828"], ["tingeypa", "709"], ["shaun", "620"], ["chrakers", "506"]]
```

If it helps the end game is to use the JSON and map it as follows:

```
players = jsonPlayers.map { Player(name: $0[0], score: $0[1]) }
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: It's an array, not a dictionary. Array of array of strings. `[[String]]`. Or `[[Any]]` if you're not sure they're all strings.

Comment: Thank you Eric, how can I rectify this within my swift code to make it compliant?

Comment: Or do i simply NOT need to convert to JSON and just use it directly?

Comment: Replace `as! [String:Any]` with `as! [[String]]`. (I have to go afk. If you're lost, someone else will be happy to help).

Comment: Thanks Eric :) If I get stuck and no one helps maybe you can be my hero later lol

Comment: Actually I suggested the expected type already in your previous question. :D

Comment: Appreciate that vadian, didn't click until read this thread. Laptop now dead so will test this out later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your JSON data isn't of type `[String:Any]`. Rather it's `[[String]]`.

So following will do the job:

```
let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [[String]]
```

But here is a handy way to do parsing JSON data.

```
enum JSONError: String, Error {
    case NoData = "ERROR: no data"
    case ConversionFailed = "ERROR: conversion from JSON failed"
}

typealias myJSONObjectType = [[String]]  // change this according to your data type that is in your JSON

func parseJSON(fromPath jsonURLString:String) {
    guard let jsonURL = URL(string: jsonURLString) else {
        print("Error creating an URL from \(jsonURLString)")
        return
    }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: jsonURL) { (data, response, error) in
        do {
            guard let data = data else {
                throw JSONError.NoData
            }
            guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? myJSONObjectType else {
                throw JSONError.ConversionFailed
            }
            print(json)
        } catch let error as JSONError {
            print(error.rawValue)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.debugDescription)
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

And use it like:

```
object.parseJSON(fromPath: "https://str8red.com/jsonoverallleaderboard/")
```

Comment: It was the string part that got it working.  Did not try the other parts but appreciate the help :)